# Change table row using Rails Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I've a simple page with link_to_remote Rails Ajax function and HTML table.
I'd like to change row of the table when click that link.

This is my html.

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td><div id="ajax_result_1">1</div></td>
        <div id="ajax_result_2"><td>2</td></div>

    </tr>
    <div id="ajax_result_3">
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    </div>
</table>
```

And this is my code.

```
<%= link_to_remote 'Change', :update => "ajax_result_1", :url => "change_path" %>
```

*change action* just render simple text.

When I use ajax_result_1 for :update, it worked okay.

But, not for *ajax_result_2* and *ajax_result_3*.

Is there a way to solve this? I want to replace row of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="ajax_result_2"><td>2</td></div>
```

this should be

```
<td><div id="ajax_result_2">2</div></td>
```

and

```
<div id="ajax_result_3">
<tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
</div>
```

should be

```
<tr  id="ajax_result_3">
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
```

you cann't use `<div>` tag in table directly if you want  to use `<div>` you have to use it in the `<td>` only.

Comment: Thanks! I thought that id attribute is only valid in div tag!